# How can I make this SQL Server script dynamic through the years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, ssms

I have code that determines the number of "lapsed" donors for each year. I have combined each year donors have lapsed using unions. I would like for this data to automatically update each year without adding in a union. Is there a way for the years to be dynamic?

I've only used the current static script I have to pull all lapsed donors since 2013. The provided script shows 2017-2019.

```
--Donated 2018, Not 2019
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PY.OppFiscalYear, COUNT(DISTINCT PY.AccountId)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT PY.AccountId, PY.OppFiscalYear
     FROM reporting.AllGifts PY
     WHERE PY.OppFiscalYear = '2018'
       AND PY.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
       AND PY.AccountRecordType = 'Household'
       AND PY.OppStage = 'Paid') PY
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT Y.AccountId
     FROM reporting.AllGifts Y
     WHERE Y.OppFiscalYear = '2019'
       AND Y.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
       AND Y.AccountRecordType = 'Household'
       AND Y.OppStage = 'Paid') Y ON PY.ACCOUNTID = Y.ACCOUNTID
WHERE 
    Y.AccountId IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    PY.OppFiscalYear

UNION

--Donated 2017, Not 2018
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PY.OppFiscalYear, COUNT(DISTINCT PY.AccountId)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT PY.AccountId, PY.OppFiscalYear
     FROM reporting.AllGifts PY
     WHERE PY.OppFiscalYear = '2017'
       AND PY.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
       AND PY.AccountRecordType = 'Household'
       AND PY.OppStage = 'Paid') PY
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT Y.AccountId
     FROM reporting.AllGifts Y
     WHERE Y.OppFiscalYear = '2018'
       AND Y.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
       AND Y.AccountRecordType = 'Household'
       AND Y.OppStage = 'Paid') Y ON PY.ACCOUNTID = Y.ACCOUNTID
WHERE 
    Y.AccountId IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    PY.OppFiscalYear
```

I expect the same output I have currently, but I want it to be able to automatically include any new donations added day by day. If I kept using my current method, the new script that would need to be added to the top with a union is for 2019 and 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how performant this will be depending on the size of your dataset but a correlated subquery should get the results you want:

```
SELECT PY.OppFiscalYear, COUNT(DISTINCT PY.AccountId)
FROM reporting.AllGifts PY
WHERE 
PY.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
        AND PY.AccountRecordType= 'Household'
        AND PY.OppStage = 'Paid'
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM  reporting.AllGifts Y
WHERE 
Y.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
        AND Y.AccountRecordType= 'Household'
        AND Y.OppStage = 'Paid'
AND Y.OppFiscalYear = PY.OppFiscalYear + 1
AND Y.AccountId = PY.AccountId)
AND OppFiscalYear <> (SELECT MAX(OppFiscalYear) FROM reporting.AllGift) -- Can't be lapsed from the latest year!
GROUP BY OppFiscalYear
```

Comment: Yes! This yielded the same results as my lengthy "unioned" scripts. Thank you! I have marked this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a basic aggregate work? I would think something this is what you are after.

```
SELECT PY.OppFiscalYear
    , COUNT(DISTINCT PY.AccountId)
FROM reporting.AllGifts PY
WHERE PY.OpportunityRecordType IN ('Classy', 'Donation', 'Pledge')
    AND PY.AccountRecordType= 'Household'
    AND PY.OppStage = 'Paid'
group by PY.OppFiscalYear
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this script does not address the lapsed donors but simply how many donors there were each year. Thank you.

Comment: Well I was basically guessing. Next time it would help considerably if you could post sample data and the desired output for that sample data.